# How to get the selected option in the Select Menu Interaction Event of JDA?

Tags: java, discord-jda

My question is how can I get the selected option, if in the **SelectionMenuEvent** event it doesn't have the method to get the option that the user selected from the menu.

My code:

````
@Override
public void execute(Member member, Message message) {
    val menu = SelectionMenu.create("help.menu");
    val command = this.loadAllCommand(message);
    command.forEach(c -> menu.addOption(c.getName(), c.getPermission(), c.getDescription(), c.getEmoji()));
    message.reply("```Diff\n" +
            "+ List of my current commands" +
            "\n```").setActionRow(menu.build()).queue();
}

// Event

@Override
    public void onSelectionMenu(SelectionMenuEvent event) {
        // get selected option of the menu
    }
````

I looked at the **SelectionMenuEvent** class documentation, let me know if I missed something.

I am using JDA version **4.4.0_350**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SelectMenuInteraction#getValues](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/interactions/components/selections/SelectionMenuInteraction.html#getValues()) or [SelectMenuInteraction#getSelectedOptions](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/interactions/components/selections/SelectionMenuInteraction.html#getSelectedOptions()). The event implements this interface.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't quite understand how the discord menu worked, and I ended up asking this silly question. Thanks a lot for the help.